# ActionMailer preview_path is not the RSpec default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, actionmailer

I have an app that's throwing the following error every time the environment is loaded.

```
Action Mailer preview_path is not the RSpec default. Preview path is set to: spec
```

I'm not even sure what the `preview_path` here is or where it might be configured. Is there a way to adjust this or disable it?

Thanks!

Comment: did you solve your issue?

Comment: Thanks for checking back! Removing that line did indeed fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have the following in your `config/environment/development.rb` file:

`config.action_mailer.preview_path = 'spec/'`

As for what the preview path is, it's [to preview emails in your browser](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#previewing-emails).

Not sure why it would be erroring. Perhaps try commenting out the config line above if you don't need email previewing?